# docker run -it over ssh: the input device is not a TTY

Tags: docker, ssh

I'd like to run a docker container interactively directly from an ssh command.

My current code appears as follows (I'm using `echo hi` as a placeholder):

```
$ ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 "docker run -ti ubuntu:xenial echo hi"
the input device is not a TTY
```

I've also tried explicitly making an interactive login shell:

```
$ ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 "bash -ilc 'docker run -ti ubuntu:xenial'"
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
the input device is not a TTY
```

If I ssh and interactively run the command, it works great:

```
$ ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-34-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
----------------------------------------------------------------
  Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS                          built 2016-08-26
----------------------------------------------------------------
Last login: Mon Oct 30 23:25:35 2017 from 10.0.2.2
vagrant@vagrant:~$ docker run -ti ubuntu:xenial echo hi
hi
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

SSH does not set up a TTY by default when an explicit command is passed on the argument list (as opposed to when running a remote interactive shell as a default operation). To work around this, add `-tt`:

```
$ ssh -tt vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 "docker run -ti ubuntu:xenial echo hi"
```

A single `-t` will set up a remote TTY if and only if a local TTY is present; `-tt` does so unconditionally.

The `RequestTTY` option can also be set explicitly, either on the command line:

```
$ ssh -o 'RequestTTY force' vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 \
>   'docker run -ti ubuntu:xenial echo hi'
```

...or in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host vagrant
    HostName 127.0.0.1
    Port 2222
    User vagrant
    RequestTTY force
```

...used as:

```
ssh vagrant 'docker run -ti ubuntu:xenial echo hi'
```

---

Quoting [the man page for `ssh`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1):

> `-t`  - Force pseudo-terminal allocation. This can be used to execute
>   arbitrary screen-based programs on    a remote machine, which can be
>   very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.     Multiple `-t`
>   options force tty allocation, even    if ssh has no local tty.

Quoting [the `ssh_config` man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5):

> `RequestTTY` - Specifies whether to request a pseudo-tty for the session.  The
>            argument may be one of: `no` (never request a TTY), `yes`
>            (always request a TTY when standard input is a TTY), `force`
>            (always request a TTY) or `auto`   (request a TTY when opening a
>            login session).  This option mirrors the -t and -T flags for
>            ssh(1).

Comment: You, sire, are a life saver.

Comment: yes very good, but it doesn't make sense to me. why would a local tty be necessary for remote tty or vice vers?

Comment: @AlexanderMills, people starting ssh at an interactive terminal expect remote commands to behave the same they would locally, meaning they expect a TTY. People running ssh from a noninteractive script without a TTY presumably want remote commands to behave the same way they would locally as well, f/e, not mixing color highlighting in with output that's going to be stored in a file or going through a pipeline. It's reasonable default behavior if one's goal is to reduce surprises for typical naive users; users who _aren't_ naive can explicitly specify what they want.